# POST Object with parent-child relationship using RestKIT

Tags: ios, http-post, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am posting data to my Rest API over the web using RestKit using following line:

```
        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:list path:@"api/lists" parameters:nil
        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
```

The object `list` I am posting has additional data named `tasks` which lies in other table i.e. standard one to many relationship. Now when I see log of POST request its body only contains `list` object data as shown below

```
request.body={"listID":0,"listName":"List 3","listSyncStatus":false}
```

but no related task data. My question is how to post whole "list" object with its relevant tasks? Can anyone guide me what would be the proper way ?

My Request Descriptor in app Delegate class is as follows

```
    //INVERSE MAPPING TO PERFORM POST FOR LIST
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[listEntityMapping inverseMapping]
                                                                               objectClass:[List class]
                                                                               rootKeyPath:nil
                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
```

and here is my `listEnityMapping`

```
//LIST RELATED REQUESTS
NSDictionary *listObjectMapping = @{
                                      @"listID" : @"listID",
                                      @"listName" : @"listName",
                                      @"listSyncStatus" : @"listSyncStatus"
                                  };

RKEntityMapping *listEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"List" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[listEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:listObjectMapping];

listEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"listID" ];
```

I do have relationship mapping as follow:

```
[listEntityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"tasks"
                                                                                      toKeyPath:@"tasks"
                                                                                    withMapping:taskEntityMapping]];
```

and my incoming json data is formatted this way

```
GET www.mydomain.com/api/lists

[ { "listID" : "96",
    "listName" : "List 1",
    "listSyncStatus" : "1",
    "tasks" : [ { "taskCompletionStatus" : "1",
          "taskID" : "67",
          "taskName" : "Task 2",
          "taskSyncStatus" : "1"
        },
        { "taskCompletionStatus" : "1",
          "taskID" : "66",
          "taskName" : "Task 1",
          "taskSyncStatus" : "1"
        }
      ]
  },
  { "listID" : "97",
    "listName" : "List 2",
    "listSyncStatus" : "1",
    "tasks" : [ { "taskCompletionStatus" : "1",
          "taskID" : "69",
          "taskName" : "Task 1",
          "taskSyncStatus" : "1"
        },
        { "taskCompletionStatus" : "1",
          "taskID" : "68",
          "taskName" : "Task 1",
          "taskSyncStatus" : "1"
        }
      ]
  }
]
```

**LOG TRACE**
I am getting idea of what could be the problem.
Following log trace came out before performing post

```
    Mapping values from object <List: 0xc1332a0> (entity: List; id: 0xc026ec0 <x-coredata://8F498A46-254D-49F3-BEF1-0B675E5AE9D9/List/p1> ; data: {
    listID = 0;
    listName = "List 1";
    listSyncStatus = 0;
    tasks =     (
        "0xc030f30 <x-coredata://8F498A46-254D-49F3-BEF1-0B675E5AE9D9/Task/p1>"
    );
}) ((null)) to object {
} with object mapping (null)

    2014-01-31 17:02:30.229 RKGist[2455:70b] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'listID' to 'listID'
2014-01-31 17:02:30.230 RKGist[2455:70b] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'listID' to 'listID'. Value: 0
2014-01-31 17:02:30.230 RKGist[2455:541f] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:130 Cached property inspection for Class 'NSMutableDictionary': {
    fileHFSFlags =     {
        isPrimitive = 1;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = fileHFSFlags;
    };
    fileHFSResourceForkSize =     {
        isPrimitive = 1;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = fileHFSResourceForkSize;
    };
}

    2014-01-31 17:02:30.230 RKGist[2455:70b] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'listName' to 'listName'
    2014-01-31 17:02:30.231 RKGist[2455:70b] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'listName' to 'listName'. Value: List 1
    2014-01-31 17:02:30.231 RKGist[2455:70b] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'listSyncStatus' to 'listSyncStatus'
    2014-01-31 17:02:30.231 RKGist[2455:70b] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'listSyncStatus' to 'listSyncStatus'. Value: 0
    2014-01-31 17:02:30.232 RKGist[2455:70b] D 2014-01-31 17:38:29.514 RKGist[2686:70b] D 

restkit.network:RKObjectParameterization.m:128 Serialized __NSCFNumber value at keyPath to __NSCFBoolean (0)
2014-01-31 17:38:29.514 RKGist[2686:70b] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1021 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2014-01-31 17:38:29.516 RKGist[2686:70b] T restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:178 POST 'http://mydomain.com/api/lists':
request.headers={
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    "User-Agent" = "RKGist/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 7.0.3; Scale/2.00)";
}
request.body={"listID":0,"listName":"List 1","listSyncStatus":false}
2014-01-31 17:38:30.227 RKGist[2686:3603] T restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:248 POST 'http://mydomain.com/api/lists' (200 OK / 1 objects) [request=0.7102s mapping=0.0012s total=0.7119s]:
response.headers={
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 31 Jan 2014 12:38:30 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=384";
    Server = Apache;
    "X-Powered-By" = "Fat-Free Framework";
}
response.body=
2014-01-31 17:38:30.228 RKGist[2686:70b] Success
```

i.e the problem would be that no relationship is found when inverse mapping is done using this dictionary

```
  NSDictionary *listObjectMapping = @{
                                      @"listID" : @"listID",
                                      @"listName" : @"listName",
                                      @"listSyncStatus" : @"listSyncStatus"
                                  };
```

my question is what should be added to this dictionary so that inverse mapping happens successfully with task? Currently list elements are mapped correctly but no associated tasks.

Comment: What relationship does `listEntityMapping` that should be inversed? You may want to create the request mapping explicitly.

Comment: @Wain added code for listEnityMapping in question.

Comment: @Wain added relationship code in question.

Comment: That would suggest that the `list` has no associated tasks as the inverse mapping should work. Turn on trace logging and see what it says. Debug to log the full `list` object before mapping starts.

Comment: @Wain i could not understand what you suggested, please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

From the information provided, your issue is that the `listEntityMapping` (or the inverse mapping created from it) don't have a relationship telling RestKit that it needs to map connected objects too.

RestKit only works with the keys that it is informed about, so you must add a relationship telling RestKit:

1. The source key in the object
2. The destination key in the JSON
3. The mapping to use on the contents found for the source key

---

Based on your additions, you need to investigate further. Add this code:

```
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

which will generate a lot of logging. Check the log at the time when you post and it should show in detail what the mapping is doing. What does it say about `tasks`?

Also, debug the `list` before you post it. Does it really have any tasks? Be sure.

Comment: addded a log level trace of post in my question/

Comment: The next few lines of log after that say nothing about tasks? The dictionary doesn't need to change, the relationship needs to exist on the inverse mapping. It looks like it should already...

Comment: Added a complete log of POST request. Check it

Comment: For some reason the relationship doesn't seem to be considered. Do you see a log like `Unable to generate inverse mapping for relationship` anywhere? Create a custom request mapping instead of using the inverse method.

Comment: at the start of log (posted above) its say `((null)) to object {
} with object mapping (null)`

is this the problem ?

Comment: No, because it then runs the mapping and you do see results. I think that is because RestKit hasn't found existing items to update... Please create a dedicated request mapping with relationship.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46516/discussion-between-umair-and-wain)